# Using DisplayNameAttribute in DevExpress PivotGridControl

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, displayname-attribute, pivot-grid

Is there any way to use [DisplayName] defined for each property as fields in a `PivotGridControl`?

```
public class Dto
{
   [DisplayName("Identifier")]
   public int Id {get;set;}
   [DisplayName("Number")]
   public string Num {get;set;}
   ...
   //other properties 
}
```

using following code cause show **Id** and **Num** as `Pivot Fields`, but I expect show **Identifire** and **Number** instead:

```
IList<Dto> result = CreateDtoList();
var bsOrderItems = new BindingSource(DataSource = result);
pivotGridControl.DataSource = bsOrderItems;
pivotGridControl.RetrieveFields();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign display names to [`Caption`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.PivotGridFieldBase.Caption.property) property of the [`field`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid.PivotGridField.class).

For example:

```
//using System.ComponentModel;
var properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(Dto));
foreach (PropertyDescriptor p in properties)
    pivotGridControl.Fields[p.Name].Caption = p.DisplayName;
```

Or you can loop on the `pivotGridControl.Fields` and for each `PivotGridField` set it's caption:

```
//using System.ComponentModel;
//using DevExpress.XtraPivotGrid;
var properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(Dto));
foreach (PivotGridField f in pivotGridControl.Fields)
    f.Caption = properties[f.FieldName].DisplayName;
```

Answer (score 1):

The DisplayName attribute should be applied correctly. Your code operates properly for me in the latest version 18.1. Alternatively, consider using [Data Annotation Attributes](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/18273/Common-Features/Data-Binding/Data-Annotation-Attributes) instead. Apply [DisplayAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to the required fields.